# How to Evaluate this Multiple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

$$\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int_{V}\frac{(b-x)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z}{\left(\sqrt{(b-x)^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3},(b>a>0)$$
$$V:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$$

Let $x=r\sin\varphi\cos\theta,y=r\sin\varphi\sin\theta,z=r\cos\varphi,J=r^2\sin\varphi.$but i still can't solve the problem.it's too complex to calculate.does anyone have a better way?

what i think:

$$\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int_{V}\frac{(b-x)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z}{\left(\sqrt{(b-x)^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3}=\oint_{x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2} \frac{\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
but it's still not easy to calculate

Answer (score 3):

When integrating over the ball $V$ of radius $a$ we choose the order of integration such that the integral with respect to $x$ is the outermost one.

For given $x\in[{-a},a]$ the variables $(y,z)$ vary over a disk $D_x$ of radius $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ centered at $(0,0)$. Furthermore we note that the integrand as a function of $y$ and $z$ is rotationally invariant. We therefore let $\rho:=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ and then obtain the following inner integral (the angular integral is for free):
$$I(x):=\int_{D_x}{b-x\over\sqrt{(b-x)^2+y^2+z^2}}\>{\rm d}(y,z)=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{b-x\over\sqrt{(b-x)^2+\rho^2}}\>\rho\>d\rho\ .$$
This gives
$$I(x)=2\pi(b-x)\sqrt{(b-x)^2+\rho^2}\>\Biggr|_{\rho=0}^{\rho=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=2\pi(b-x)\left(\sqrt{b^2+a^2-2bx}-(b-x)\right)\ .$$
The final result is then
$$=\int_{-a}^aI(x)\>dx\ ,$$
which I may leave to you.

Comment: i find another easier way to understand:let $x=x,y=r\cos\theta,z=r\sin\theta$ S.T. $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta\int_{-a}^{a}dx\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \frac{(b-x)rdr}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+r^2}}$$thanks for your nicely explaination

Comment: It's the same way.